# Custom Sort in C# LINQ with LAMBDA

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, lambda

Even thought there's another topic with similar title, i search for a more generic answer.

I have a SQLSERVER Query to select userId's with a custom `Order By` clause. Something like this:

```
SELECT userID
FROM users
WHERE userName like '%whatever%'
ORDER BY 
 CASE
  WHEN UserID = 123 THEN 0
  WHEN UserID = 456 THEN 1
  WHEN UserID = 789 THEN 2
  ELSE 3
 END ASC,
 UserID
```

So, how do i replicate the same `Order By` structure, but using LINQ with LAMBDA in C#?

Here is my code so far:

```
var userID = db.User.Where(x => x.userName.Contains("whatever").OrderBy(x => x.userID).Select(x => x.userID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ORDER BY 
 CASE
  WHEN UserID = 123 THEN 0
  WHEN UserID = 456 THEN 1
  WHEN UserID = 789 THEN 2
  ELSE 3
 END ASC,
 UserID
```

is functionally equivalent to this Lambda

```
.OrderBy(_ => _.userID == 123 ? 0 : _.userID == 456 ? 1 : _.userID == 789 ? 2 : 3)
.ThenBy(_ => _.userID)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this heavily rely on them knowing what values are expected? If that's just a sample query, and the values are potentially different in their working environment, this won't work.

Comment: I know the values i want to get on top of the sort. I dont and dont need to know the subsequent values of the sort.